# Polymer seed - custom element dependencies

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to create custom polymer element using [polymer seed](https://github.com/PolymerElements/seed-element). This element is dependent of **pdf.js**, which I include in the beginning of my element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<script src="../pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js"/>

<dom-module id="my-element">

...
```

When I run `polyserve` I got an error:

```
hydrolysis-analyzer.html:104 Failed to load source at:
http://localhost:8080/components/pdf-element/pdf-element.html ... 
Error parsing script in http://localhost:8080/components/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js at 3:1(…)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Is it me who is putting dependency wrong? (How should I manage element's dependency properly?)
Or there is something wrong with configuration/version of seed project?  Just in case it could be related I'm using `iron-component-page` version 1.1.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooops... The problem was in the `script` tag, instead of

```
<script src="../pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js"/>
```

should be:

```
<script src="../pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js"></script
```

Comment: That solves the problem itself, but I'd like to add something, when you add a third party js library in a polymer element, the [recommended practice](https://youtu.be/Fsxeh4Mj36w?t=2m33s) is to create an html file with just the script tags and then import that file into your custom element (I think it's to prevent the library from being loaded multiple times if you create multiple instances of the same element or something like that)